# set partial view inside bootstrap modal window

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I have partial view like

```
<div data-id="myModal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
   ....
   some content
</div>
```

How can I on page load set this partial inside modal bootstrap window
I tried with

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

but that doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Change

`<div data-id="myModal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">`

to

`<div id="myModal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">`

Answer (score 0):

To apply modal to html, first you must render html partial on page and then you can call your javascript like so:

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/partial/myModal.cshtml");}

<script type="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
</script>
```

You may consider set a proper id for your modal `id="myModal"` instead of `data-id="myModal"`.